# How can i provide values for @exampleProperty annotation from external resource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I need to set a dynamic list of Example properties  as parameters for ApiResponse

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200,message = "Successfully"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400,
                     message = "Bad Request",
                     examples = @Example(value  ={
                             **@ExampleProperty**(mediaType = "application/json",value = "\"400\": \"The format of field Value1 is invalid.\""),
                             **@ExampleProperty**(mediaType = "application/json",value = "\"400\": \"The format of field Value2 is invalid.\""),
                             **@ExampleProperty**  ....
                            }))
})
```

How can i provide values for @ExampleProperty from external resource file instead of harcoding ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "dynamic list"? Do you mean multiple different examples?

Comment: @Helen : yes, how can i pass a mutiple ExampleProperties from json file exactly .